# How to set Hikari Pool MaximumSize

Tags: java, spring-boot

Hikari size set total 1 how to set in dbConfig

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement()
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "entitymangaer",transactionManagerRef="transactionManager",basePackages="com.master.dto")
public class DbConfig {
    
     @Bean
        @Primary
        @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
        public HikariDataSource memberDataSourceProperties() {
            return new HikariDataSource();
        }
        
        @Bean(name ="erp_cha_ngpillai")
        @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.configuration")
        public DataSource datasourceMaster() {
            memberDataSourceProperties().setMaximumPoolSize(1);
            memberDataSourceProperties().setUsername("test");
            memberDataSourceProperties().setPassword("test");
            memberDataSourceProperties().setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?sessionVariables=sql_mode='NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'&jdbcCompliantTruncation=false");
            memberDataSourceProperties().setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            return memberDataSourceProperties();
        }
   

    @Bean(name = "entitymangaer")
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean masterEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,@Qualifier("erp_cha_ngpillai") DataSource dataSource) {

        return  builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages(PlaceOrganizationDao.class).build(); 
    }

    @Bean(name ="transactionManager")
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager  masterManager(@Qualifier("entitymangaer") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory)
    {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).